# Router-outlet and footer in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am creating an application which will have two sections. The first section will load depending on the route. The second second will be a footer which will be same in all views.

**index.html**

```
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: '',  component: HomeComponent }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <router-outlet><router-outlet>
 <app-footer></app-footer>
```

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

**home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent { }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div>
<p>Home page will come here</p>
</div>
```

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-footer',
templateUrl: './footer.component.html'
})

export class FooterComponent {}
```

**footer.component.html**

```
<p>Footer will come here</p>
```

**The screen displays this**

Footer will come here

Home page will come here

---

I expect the router-outlet to render the HomeComponent first. Then, the app-footer component should be loaded. But, its being rendered in the opposite order.

What can I do to make them render in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at https://github.com/g7bhatia/stackexample this only app folder content and it is printing as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does work, what changes did you make? Also, I see a route for the FooterComponent, is that needed?

Comment: Great..always try to make your component with the command given. Command: ng g component yourComponentName.                                                         
it will auto update all the modules.

Comment: Okay, and what does the OnInit do? Is it needed?